# Material UI: Get value of Textfield when clicking InputAdornment

Tags: javascript, select, material-ui

I'm trying to get value of `Textfield` after clicking the `InputAdornment` icon. When using `OnChange`, things were looking fine, now I'm getting `undefined`

```
<Textfield
    id="search"
    label="SEARCH"
    InputProps={{
     endAdornment: 
       <InputAdornment position="end">
         <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} onClick={(e) =>console.log(e.target.value)} />. 
       </InputAdornment> )
    }}
 />
```

Comment: Isn’t it better if you put your onClick function as attribute of textfield? Because now you are trying read the value of the icon.

Comment: Also I don't see that you are updating the value of text field onChange. so add onChange for sure. Also with current version onclick console.log event.target, so you can see which element you are targeting. if it is the one you want, you dont need to change your onClick function.

Answer (score 0):

For React, you should save your search term as a state in your component.

```
function SeachComponent() {
    
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");


    function handleChange(event) {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value)
    }

    function handleButtonClick() {
        console.log(searchTerm);
    }

    return (
       <Textfield
            id="search"
            label="SEARCH"
            onChange={handleChange}
            InputProps={{
               endAdornment: 
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                     <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} onClick={onIconClick} />. 
               </InputAdornment> )
            }}
         />
     );

}
```